# How to get page object relative to another page object in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for solution how to get page object relative to another object in Page Object Model for selenium webdriver

Code of my test:

```
class StartPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='widget']//a[text()='link text']")
    WebElement linkInWidget;

    public void clickLink() {
        linkInWidget.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, NextPage.class);

    }

 }
```

Next page

```
class NextPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='widget']//input[@type='button']")
    WebElement buttonInWidget;

    @FindBy(id = "Index")
    WebElement index;

    public void clickButton() {
        buttonInWidget.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, NextPage.class);

    }

    public String getText() {
        return index.getText();                 
   }

 }
```

Configuration class

```
public class ConfigureTest{

   protected WebDriver driver;
   protected String baseUrl;
   protected StartPage startPage;
   protected NextPage nextPage ;

   @BeforeSuite
   public void setUp() {
         baseUrl = "http://webapp.com/";
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   }


   @AfterSuite
   public void tearDown() throws Exception {
         driver.quit();

   }
}
```

And class of my test

```
public class SomeTest extends ConfigureTest {

   @Test
   public void testLinkAndButton() throws Exception {

          startPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SomePage.class);
          driver.get(baseUrl);

          nextPage = startPage.clickLink();
          nextPage.clickButton();
          String data = nextPage.getText();

   }
}
```

In both classes FirstPage and NextPage i find elements by xpath which has same first part **//div[@class='widget']** it mean that all elements like buttons and links are under this widget and i have same xpath for widgets in my all pages

**Problem**: if only xpath of my widget will be changed i must make changes in all page objects of my test

**Question**: Is in any way how to improve my test for more flexibility with usage like:

```
page().get(Widget.class, "Widget name").get(Button.class, "Button name").click
```

**Update**: I resolve part of this problem in such way:
I create classes of my UI elements with get methods which can return objects of any class:

Class of Widget object

```
public class widget{
    WebDriver driver;

    public widget (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    // Find a single element
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='tsf-p']")
    WebElement linkInWidget;

    public void click() {
        linkInWidget.click();
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> expectedPage, String uiclass){
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, expectedPage);
    }


}
```

Class of Button object

```
public class Button {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Button (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(name="btnG")
    WebElement button;

    public void click() {
        button.click();
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> expectedPage){
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, expectedPage);
    }


}
```

Class of HomePage

```
public class HomePage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='widget']//a[text()='']")
    WebElement linkInWidget;

    public void click() {
        linkInWidget.click();
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> expectedPage, String name){

        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, expectedPage);
    }

}
```

My test

```
public class searchTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com.ua/");
    }

    @Test
    public void testUI() {
        HomePage homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
        widget widget = PageFactory.initElements(driver, widget.class);

        homePage.get(widget.class).get(Input.class).setValue("yahoo");
        homePage.get(widget.class).get(Button.class).click();

   }
```

}

And a result is that we can compose any object by using our classes

```
homePage.get(widget.class).get(Input.class).setValue("yahoo");
```

**But** how to get element by it name or number for example:

```
homePage.get(widget.class, "Name").get(Input.class, 1).setValue("yahoo");
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a public repository [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG) where I have implemented PageObject and `PageFactory` concept with `TestNG`. You are probably looking for a better way to inherit BaseClasse. The common methods should be placed in BaseClass and available to all PageObjects through inheritance. I have everything placed in GitHub and it's too broad to implement here.

Comment: thank you for our answer, i think that here i should use generics because get method doesn't know which object will be returned

Comment: Can you please clarify more?

Comment: i'am not sure, but i think there should be created classes for different UI elements like widget, button, link , etc And we shoud have access to create objects of this classes and return this objects and as result we can collect page object from 2 or 3 objects and make some action with it

Comment: It depends on your application I guess. There is not bindings you have to create single page object for a single page of the application but just for the sake of complexity people do that.